# How to use VBA to extract the data after the right arrow?

Tags: excel, vba, filter

[image]

Hello everyone,

I'm doing a challenging task assigned by my supervisor but I'm not sure how to solve this problem. The task that I want to do is to extract the values after the right arrow in column B (Input) and paste it in column C (Output). If there is only one value in the cell (e.g. B4,B8,B9,...), then the output in column C will just be the value.  If the cell in column B is empty, then just leave the output column as blank. So the final output should be exactly the same as column C. May I know is there any way to achieve it using VBA scripting? I know that this can be done without using VBA, but I'm requested to use VBA to solve this problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are there spaces between the first number, the arrow and the last one? What character is that 'arrow'?

Comment: Do it using the same logic in VBA. What have you tried? Where have you run into problems?

Comment: @FaneDuru, Yes, there is a space between first number and the arrow, and another space between arow and last number. I'm not sure what is the character of the arrow, but basically I'm just copying the data from this website:https://www.marketbeat.com/stocks/NASDAQ/AAPL/price-target/     The data is under the ` price target` column in the table

Comment: If it is a space, no matter of the character type. It should be a UNICODE character, probably 27F6. I will post a piece of code which I hope solve your problem.

Comment: If you want checking my supposition, selecte a cell and then run the  next code line: `ActiveCell.Value = ChrW(&H27F6)`. Does it create an arrow similar to the existing  one?

Comment: Or try `ActiveCell.Value = ChrW(&H279D)`, if the used arrow is a little shorter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next function, please:

```
Function extractValLngArrSep(str As String) As Double
  Dim x: x = Split(str, " ")

   'For the case of empty cell - it will return 0:
   If str = "" Then extractValLngArrSep = 0: Exit Function
   If UBound(x) > 0 Then
        extractValLngArrSep = x(2)
   Else
        extractValLngArrSep = x(0)
   End If
End Function
```

It can be tested with the next testing `Sub`. It can be easily applied to all column, just iterating through its cells. Now, please activate one of such a cell with separated numbers and run the code. Then one cell having a simple number:

```
Sub testExtractVal()
  ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = extractValLngArrSep(ActiveCell.Value)
End Sub
```

It should be also adapted to catch the case of a single string instead of a number, but this is something out of the question and not very difficult to be handled (I think...).

To process your example range, please use the next code:

```
Sub testExtractValBis()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, C As Range

 Set sh = ActiveSheet ' please, use here your necessary sheet
 lastRow = sh.Range("B" & sh.Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 For Each C In sh.Range("B3:B" & lastRow)
    If C.value <> "" Then
       C.Offset(0, 1).Value = extractValLngArrSep(C.Value)
    End Iff
 Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks FaneDuru, the code works  for me! However, when the cell in column B is empty, the output in column C will be 0 instead of blank. I tried to change this line of code: `If str = "" Then extractValLngArrSep = 0: Exit Function` to `If str = "" Then extractValLngArrSep = "": Exit Function`, but it will create an error and the loop will stop at the Row 12. May I know how should I deal with this situation?

Comment: @weizer: You cannot do that, because of the fact that the function returns a `Double`... If you need an empty string, there are other ways to accomplish that. The simple way should be to skip calling the function in case of an empty cell. Another way should be to analize the function returned value and write "" instead of zero. And many other ways... I will adapt the above (last) code to skip the function call...

Comment: @weizer: Adapted it. Does it work now as you need?

Comment: @Glad I could help! If you would confirm what king of character is that (special) longer arrow, the function could be adapted exactly to it. I mean, the separator in the `Split` function, could be `" " & ChrW(&H279D) & " "` (most probably), or `" " & ChrW(&H27F6) & " "`, according to your real existing separator... I suggested you, in a comment, how to test that...

Comment: Seems like when I'm using `" " & ChrW(&H279D) & " "`, there will be an error for `extractValLngArrSep = x(2)`, if I'm using `" " & ChrW(&H27F6) & " "`, there will be error for `extractValLngArrSep = x(0)`

Comment: @weizer: But I did not say that it will work with the same function... Another function must be created, using the split on that specific structure. I could do it, but you did  not confirm what character is there in your string...

Answer (score 1):

### Extract After Character

- Adjust the values in the constants section.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub extractAfterChar()
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const srcFirst As String = "B3"
    Const dstfirst As String = "C3"
    Dim Delimiter As String: Delimiter = ChrW(10141)
    ' Define workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' Workbook containing this code.
    ' Declare variables
    Dim rg As Range ' Source Range
    Dim wrCount ' Worksheet Rows Count
    ' Define Source Range.
    With wb.Worksheets(wsName).Range(srcFirst)
        wrCount = .Worksheet.Rows.Count
        Set rg = .Resize(wrCount - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious) ' Define Last Cell Range.
        If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' Validate Last Cell Range.
        Set rg = .Resize(rg.Row - .Row + 1) ' Define Source Range.
    End With
    ' Write Source Range's Rows Count to a variable.
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
    ' Write values from Source Range to Data Array.
    Dim Data As Variant
    If rCount > 1 Then
        Data = rg.Value ' multiple rows (cells)
    Else
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Value ' one row (cell) only
    End If
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim Key As Variant ' Current Value (in Data Array)
    Dim i As Long ' Data Array Row Counter
    ' Replace values in Data Array with results.
    For i = 1 To rCount
        Key = Data(i, 1)
        If IsError(Key) Then
            Data(i, 1) = Empty
        Else
            If Len(Key) = 0 Then ' empty or blank ("")
                Data(i, 1) = Empty
            Else
                Key = Val(rightString(Key, Delimiter))
                If Key = 0 Then
                    Data(i, 1) = Empty
                Else
                    Data(i, 1) = Key
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    ' Write values from Data Array to Destination Range.
    With wb.Worksheets(wsName).Range(dstfirst)
        .Resize(wrCount - .Row + 1).ClearContents ' from first to bottom-most
        .Resize(rCount).Value = Data
    End With
End Sub

Function rightString( _
    ByVal SearchString As String, _
    Optional ByVal Delimiter As String = ",", _
    Optional ByVal doTrim As Boolean = True) _
As String
    Dim slen As Long: slen = Len(SearchString)
    If slen = 0 Then Exit Function
    Dim sPos As Long: sPos = InStr(1, SearchString, Delimiter)
    If sPos > 0 Then
        rightString = Right(SearchString, slen - sPos)
    Else
        rightString = SearchString
    End If
    If doTrim Then
        rightString = Trim(rightString)
    End If
End Function
```